# How to group elements using Linq in my case?

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to group by `Amount`. But, everytime the amount changes sequentially it should be in separate group. In my case it places all items with `Amount=100` in a single group like in `Actual result` instead of putting the last one in a separate group. I can write a simple loop that can do that, but I want to do this with Linq.

**TestData**

```
{
  { 0, 100 },
  { 1, 100 },
  { 2, 10  },
  { 3, 100 }
}
```

**Expected result**

```
Group1: { {0,100}, {1,100} }
Group2: { {2,10} }
Group3: { {3,100} }
```

**Actual result**

```
Group1: { {0,100}, {1,100}, {3,100} }
Group2: { {2,10} }
```

**Code**

```
class MyClass
{
   public int Index {get; set;}
   public int Amount {get; set;}
}

var data = new List<MyClass> 
{ 
   new MyClass{Index=0,Amount=100},
   new MyClass{Index=1,Amount=100},
   new MyClass{Index=2,Amount=10},
   new MyClass{Index=3,Amount=100}
};

var itemsByAmount = data.GroupBy(d => d.Amount).Select(gd => gd.Select(d => d));
```

Comment: Can you explain _” the amount changes sequentially”_? I’m not sure what that means, is it something like “it’s larger than the one before”?

Comment: I didn't know how to describe it so I called it sequentialy. But, the `expected result` in my post is what I want to reach eventually with Linq. By "sequentially" I mean it should not skip over new Amount. If amount changes it should be put in a new group.

Comment: Even if you could write a GroupBy that kept track of the previous item - and I have no clue how that would work - a ‘simple loop’ sounds like a better option.

Comment: I probably thought there is already a built-in solution. I'll use a simple loop then.

Answer (score 2):

my understanding is that you want to group `Amounts` that are sequentially connected when creating groups.

I think the `Aggregate` method meets your requirements.

Below is a sample code:

```
using System.Text.Json;

var sourceDate = new List<MyClass>() {
    new MyClass{ Index = 1,Amount=100 },
    new MyClass{ Index = 2,Amount=100 },
    new MyClass{ Index = 3,Amount=10 },
    new MyClass{ Index = 4,Amount=100 }
};

var group = sourceDate.Aggregate(
            new List<KeyValueGroup>(),
            (groups, item) =>
            {
                var last = groups.LastOrDefault();
                if (last?.GroupKey == item.Amount)
                {
                    last.keyValues.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    groups.Add(new KeyValueGroup(item));
                }

                return groups;
            });

group.ForEach(item =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(item));
});



class KeyValueGroup
{
    public KeyValueGroup(MyClass item)
    {
        GroupKey = item.Amount;
        keyValues = new List<MyClass>() { item };
    }
    public int GroupKey { get; set; }

    public List<MyClass> keyValues { get; set; }
}

class MyClass
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

output:

```
{"GroupKey":100,"keyValues":[{"Index":1,"Amount":100},{"Index":2,"Amount":100}]}
{"GroupKey":10,"keyValues":[{"Index":3,"Amount":10}]}
{"GroupKey":100,"keyValues":[{"Index":4,"Amount":100}]}
```